# R: Find row contianing string in data.frame and edit different cell in same row

Tags: r

I have one data.frame with a list of products and their costs that Ill call `COSTOFGOOD`.

Another data.frame has this months sales, which Ill call `SALESREPORT`.

I want R to go through `COSTOFGOOD` row by row, compare the column `COSTOFGOOD$ProductID` with `SALESREPORT$ProductID`and if it finds it there too, add the content from `COSTOFGOOD$ProductCOST`to the same row in `SALESREPORT$ProductCOST`.

Here are 2 sample Dataframes

```
ProductID <- c('AA','BB','CC','DD','EE')
ProductNAME <- c('Dress1', 'Dress2', 'Dress3','Dress4','Dress5')
ProductPRICE <- c('22', '15', '16', '18', '19')
ProductCOST <- c(' ', ' ', ' ',' ', ' ')
ProductPROFIT <- c('21', '13', '13', '14', '14')

SALESREPORT <- data.frame(ProductID, ProductNAME, ProductPRICE, ProductCOST, ProductPROFIT)

ProductID <- c('DD','BB','CC','AA','GG','JJ')
ProductNAME <- c('Dress4', 'Dress2', 'Dress3','Dress1', 'Dress34','Dress15')
ProductPRICE <- c('22', '15', '16', '18', '20','54')
ProductCOST <- c('1', '2', '3', '4','5', '6')
ProductPROFIT <- c('21', '13', '13', '14','7','9')

COSTOFGOOD<- data.frame(ProductID, ProductNAME, ProductPRICE, ProductCOST, ProductPROFIT)

#Turning the first column into rownames as I need that for the code I wrote so far
rownames(COSTOFGOOD)<-COSTOFGOOD[[1]]
```

The result should fill the empty column `ProductCOST` in `SALESREPORT`

```
  ProductID ProductNAME ProductPRICE ProductCOST ProductPROFIT
1        AA      Dress1           22                        21
2        BB      Dress2           15                        13
3        CC      Dress3           16                        13
4        DD      Dress4           18                        14
5        EE      Dress5           19                        14
```

With the content from `ProductCOST` in `COSTOFGOOD`, but only when the `ProductID` is found in `SALESREPORT`.

```
   ProductID ProductNAME ProductPRICE ProductCOST ProductPROFIT
DD        DD      Dress4           22           1            21
BB        BB      Dress2           15           2            13
CC        CC      Dress3           16           3            13
AA        AA      Dress1           18           4            14
GG        GG     Dress34           20           5             7
JJ        JJ     Dress15           54           6             9
```

And here is the code I have written so far, that is returning an error though:

```
for (f in rownames(COSTOFGOOD)) {

  ROW_SALESREPORT <- rownames(SALESREPORT[grep(f, SALESREPORT$ProductID),])

  for(i in seq_len(nrow(COSTOFGOOD))) {

    COST <- COSTOFGOOD$ProductCOST[i]
    SALESREPORT$ProductCOST[ROW_SALESREPORT] <- COST

  }


}
```

It gives me this Error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "ProductCOST", value = c(1L, 1L, 1L,  : 
  replacement has 6 rows, data has 5
In addition: Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ROW_SALESREPORT, value = 6L) :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

Here is a break down of what I was thinking while writing that. There are probably a lot easier ways, but I cant seem to find anything that does what grep and sed do in combination in bash for R:

1. In the first `for loop` `f` is the `ProductID`. I use `grep` to find the `ProductID` in `SALESREPORT`. I then save the `rowname` in which it was found in `ROW_SALESREPORT`.
2. I start a second `for loop` that has the purpose to copy the content of `COSTOFGOOD$ProductCOST` of the corresponding `ProductID`. I save it in `COST`
3. I add the content of `COST` in the corresponding cell in `SALESREPORT$ProductCOST[ROW_SALESREPORT]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can also be done with a join in `dplyr`.

I assume here that `ProductID` is a sufficient key to connect the two tables. I removed the empty `ProductCOST` from `SALESREPORT`, and then connect each of those rows to the row in COSTOFGOOD that matches, only bringing in the ProductID and ProductCOST columns.

```
SALESREPORT %>% 
  select(-ProductCOST) %>%
  left_join(COSTOFGOOD %>% select(ProductID, ProductCOST), 
                          by = "ProductID")


  ProductID ProductNAME ProductPRICE ProductPROFIT ProductCOST
1        AA      Dress1           22            21           4
2        BB      Dress2           15            13           2
3        CC      Dress3           16            13           3
4        DD      Dress4           18            14           1
5        EE      Dress5           19            14          NA
```

**Sample data**

```
SALESREPORT <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  ProductID = c("AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE"),
  ProductNAME = c("Dress1", "Dress2", "Dress3", "Dress4", "Dress5"),
  ProductPRICE = c(22L, 15L, 16L, 18L, 19L),
  ProductCOST = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
  ProductPROFIT = c(21L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L)
)

COSTOFGOOD <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  ProductID = c("DD", "BB", "CC", "AA", "GG", "JJ"),
  ProductNAME = c(
    "Dress4", "Dress2", "Dress3", "Dress1", "Dress34",
    "Dress15"
  ),
  ProductPRICE = c(22L, 15L, 16L, 18L, 20L, 54L),
  ProductCOST = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L),
  ProductPROFIT = c(21L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 7L, 9L)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let me coerce your columns 3 to 5 to class `"numeric"`.

```
COSTOFGOOD[3:5] <- lapply(COSTOFGOOD[3:5], function(f) as.numeric(levels(f))[f])
SALESREPORT[3:5] <- lapply(SALESREPORT[3:5], function(f) as.numeric(levels(f))[f])
```

Now, the problem.
You can match the rows of both dataframes with `merge` and then use `rowSums` to add the values. Finally, assign the result to the original `SALESREPORT` column.

```
mrg <- merge(SALESREPORT[c(1, 4)], COSTOFGOOD[c(1, 4)], by = "ProductID")
Sum <- rowSums(mrg[-1], na.rm = TRUE)

i <- match(mrg[["ProductID"]], SALESREPORT[["ProductID"]])
SALESREPORT[["ProductCOST"]][i] <- Sum[i]

rm(mrg, Sum, i)    # tidy up
```